# Mongoose statics is not working with async and await

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I have one mongoose model where I declared 1 statics which should return me all features.

```
const Feature = require('./featureModel')

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const schemaOptions = {
  timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
};

const ModemSchema = new Schema({
  proxy_type: {
    type: String,
    default: 'None'
  },
  data_prioritization: {
    type: String,
    default: 'None'
  }
}, schemaOptions);


ModemSchema.statics.possibleProxyTypes = async function () {
  features = await Feature.find({})
  return features
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Modem', ModemSchema);
```

`Modem.possibleProxyTypes` I am calling it like this (class method)
But await is not waiting and I am getting output `[AsyncFunction]` . Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Is it possible you forgot the parentheses?  `Modem.possibleProxyTypes()`

Comment: `Promise { <pending> }` This is what I get when I call `Modem.possibleProxyTypes()` @AsafAviv

Comment: yea an `async` function always return a promise, you have to call `.then()` or `await` on the promise even if you `await` for it in the called function

Comment: But mongoose query also return promise and that's why I have added async and await . I am using same type of code in my controllers its working there but not here @AsafAviv

Comment: You actually don't even need `async` here and just `return Feature.find({})`. but that doesn't matter in this case, include the code in your controller

Comment: No actually I need it here I need to add more logic into it before I return value and I want to do it with asyn/await  syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it worked like this. ( If you had added all the related codes to the question, I would say where was the problem.)

Modem Schema: ( almost no change, I only added let features, and console.log)

```js
ModemSchema.statics.possibleProxyTypes = async function() {
  letfeatures = await Feature.find({});
  console.log(features);
  return features;
};
```

And I tried this in a sample get route like this:

```js
const Feature = require("../models/featureModel");
const Modem = require("../models/modemModel");

router.get("/modem", async (req, res) => {
  const features = await Modem.possibleProxyTypes();
  res.send(features);
});
```

Maybe the problem was that you didn't use await here in this line:

```
await Modem.possibleProxyTypes()
```

This returned me features like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e0207ff4323c7545026b82a",
        "name": "Feature 1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e0208054323c7545026b82b",
        "name": "Feature 2",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: I was calling `Modem.possibleProxyTypes()` it from console, your code is working but I am still confused in statics method I wrote same thing async with await and Mongooes query returns promise so it should work. 

You are doing same thing calling `Modem.possibleProxyTypes()` in async & await function and `Modem.possibleProxyTypes()` this also returning promise

Comment: Or I think issue is that I am calling it from  node console, if I call this direclty in code when exectution control is coming then it will work. I am checking this